# Very odd edit has me wondering if mass incompetence or something worse?

Tags: discussion, edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13319350

has a trivial edit, which makes a few things wrong (prime numbers now contains "4" instead of "3")

It also has the unnecessary English addition to "you may dereference" converting it to "you may want to dereference"

I can understand the last change as a regional difference, but out of four votes, only one indicated that it didn't contribute much, if anything to the readability while three other reviewers accepted.

Is this some sort of "review" abuse, or just a bunch of reviewers being lazy?  If it could be gaming the system, exactly what is there to gain?

Comment: I agree with their reason for making the edit. I think they should have just replaced the array name also.

Comment: @4castle - What reason? The edit was worthless. It did nothing to improve the answer, and seems to be borderline trolling. I'm dealing with the reviewers involved, because I see no reason this should have been approved.

Comment: @BradLarson Their comment on the edit was `changed the second spot in array from 3 to 4 because it makes the point more clear that we're moving forward a spot in memory, not incrementing the value`. It seems to me like a valid edit to clarify the example.

Comment: @4castle - The array is clearly labeled `primes`. At best, this is changing the intent of an answerer, which is not what edits should do. Any code edit should be reviewed stringently, and these reviewers did not do their job.

Comment: @BradLarson The intent of the answer wasn't to show what the first 8 prime numbers are, the intent was just to show an example array with dummy values. It just so happened that the dummy values were misleading. I don't see how that's trivial.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Any Java programmer who had never seen pointers before, and saw a variable with seemingly type `int` with a value of `2` change to `3` because of a `++` would think that perhaps it was because the value was incremented. Examples speak louder than words, and this example was ill-contrived.

Comment: It's not that they think there's anything special about the number 2, it's that when the array begins with 2, 3 then `*(intPointer+1)` and `(*intPointer)+1` are both equal to `3` making it ambiguous what has happened. Using any number other than 3 removes the ambiguity.

Comment: @BradLarson This seems like an unusual reason to punish the reviewers. They did their job, they just didn't improve the edit further like they probably should have. Rejecting the edit would have been a bad choice, because then the problem with the example would still remain.

Comment: @4castle  Please keep in mind that the reviewer's job is to assure the edit improves the answer.  In this case, under you reasoning (which I'm not certain is the real reasoning of the person making the post) it didn't improve the post because it didn't go far enough.  If we had a list of prime numbers, and you change one to prevent a different issue, you don't keep the rest of the post referring to prime numbers.

Comment: The rest of the post never actually referred to the array as containing prime numbers, so it wouldn't have obstructed your post at all. I don't think anyone will start questioning their knowledge of mathematics because of the array. They are here to learn about pointers.

Comment: @4castle Although I really didn't agree with your reasoning, we are talking about reasoning upon a mis-reasoning, and it's an odd place, where a lot of possible mis-reasonings might exist.  Since the prime number sequence is 2, 3 and that's incremental, I've changed the post to be squares, and taken the 0, 1 incremental as the first step plus added as second 1, 4 step just to make sure they don't think we're just adding.  I hope this satisfies many, if not all.  I would have hoped that the sequence 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, ... as prime numbers, but apparently some think it's incremental!

Comment: That is much better. (Though you could have started the squares at 1 probably without incident)

Comment: @4castle Don't push it, you just argued that 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, ... is often mistaken for incrementing. :)  If they read the example now, and see the transition between 1 and 4, and still think it's counting, they have other prerequisites to learn before understanding the difference between a Java reference and a C pointer.

Comment: Well no, I was only saying that `2` -> `3` could be mistaken for incrementing. Your post didn't show results beyond `3` before.

Comment: If I have more energy for yet another update, sure I'll accommodate the suggested change, but in pursuit of the lowest common denominator of programmer (who still needs to know the difference between a pointer and a reference in two different languages), I would have hoped a prime number sequence wouldn't have been updated to include 4.  That's a little too "lowest common denominator" for me :)  Cheers, and please, take it in a joking mood.  We have programmers that know about pointers and references, but not prime numbers!

Comment: Apparently one can be an [expert in primes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primes). Lots of down votes there. Maybe we ought to burn it down.

Comment: This kind of nonsense on SO drives me crazy.  Trollish, indeed.

Comment: related: [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can't say there was anything malicious or underhanded here. Four people reviewed it, three approved. The only reject, interestingly enough, was from the only person who has any significant rep in the Java tag. The three approvers also have just over 2k rep which means they're new to reviewing edits in general. I would chalk the approval up to not understanding what the change actually meant to the code.

I disagree that it was correct to make the edit in the first place. I would have rejected the edit for this reason

> clearly conflicts with author's intent
>   **This edit deviates from the original intent of the post.** Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

What the defenders of the edit are missing is that the changing of the number **changed the meaning**. That it was named `primes` is NOT irrelevant. Good code always seeks to name variables with some sort of meaning as to what the variable means or contains. Whether or not the editor found it confusing, he should not have edited it as he did. `4` is clearly not a prime number.

The final nail in the coffin here is that this post was **6 years old**. Nobody else found it confusing enough to edit it or even post a comment (and the original poster is the OP of this thread so he's active). If the editor found it that confusing he should have asked another question, referencing this answer.

Comment: Nothing in the help page prohibits you from changing the meaning, in fact we are suggested that if we can salvage a question by changing the meaning, to please do so.

Comment: "If the editor found it that confusing he should have asked another question, referencing this answer." - um, no? The editor understood the concept, and attempted to make it less confusing. Didn't quite do it as well as they should've, but there was no need for another question there.